# Sculpt mode grease pencil change to 2d tool

Tags: sculpt-mode

I was working in a 2D proyect, using 2D sculpt tool but then it changed to a 3D sculpt mode and i dont know how to get back the 2D sculpt mode i was using before.

[image]